# Spring bean in Configuration class not being autowired in a bean defined in .xml file

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a config class where I create a bean which I'm using in another bean declared in a xml file. When I try to use it from the xml defined bean it throws a NPE because it was never autowired.
I have scanned the package where I'm autowiring the config bean but even with that is not taking it.

`MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java`

```
package org.util;

public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> propertiesConfigurationBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, Properties props) throws BeansException {
        super.processProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, props);
        //breaks due to NPE
        FileBasedConfiguration configuration = propertiesConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration();
    }
}
```

`applicationContext.xml`

```
    <bean id="myBean" class="org.util.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <ref bean="appProps" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.util" />
```

`PropertiesFileConfiguration.java`

```
package org.configuration;

@Configuration
public class PropertiesFileConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> propertiesConfigurationBuilder() {
        PropertiesBuilderParameters properties = new Parameters().properties();
        properties.setFileName("application.properties");

        FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
                new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(PropertiesConfiguration.class);
        builder.setAutoSave(true);

        return builder.configure(properties);
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring 4.3.26. NOT using SpringBoot.

Comment: NPE almost always indicates that you're using a different instance than the Spring bean. Switch to constructor injection and see what breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try specifying the required autowire dependency in your XML instead:

If you add a public setter for `propertiesConfigurationBuilder` in `MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, in your XML you can provide your configuration builder bean as the setter argument for your property placeholder bean like so (`ref` is the name of your bean, `name` is the field to set):

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.util.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <ref bean="appProps" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="propertiesConfigurationBuilder" ref="propertiesConfigurationBuilder" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Perfect, this one worked for me. So, the issue was that I was trying to use both annotations and xml configuration in same bean and that was why it failed?

Comment: I think you should be able to use both. The above was my first thought to fix your problem since that's how I usually inject my XML beans. To use both together I think you may be able to do it by adding this in your bean XML: `<context:annotation-config/>` (though I can't say 100% it'll work since I haven't tested it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this @ComponentScan(" put Your base package here ") on you config class